# Binding a ComboBox to two sources

Tags: .net, winforms, binding, combobox, bindingsource

So I've got a `List<T>` that I bind my `ComboBox` to through a `BindingSource`. Works fine, no problem. Now I need to add one more item to my `ComboBox` that is not available in the List (and I can't modify contents of the List either). The following schemes come to my mind:

1. Create a copy of the original List and add one more item to it before binding.
2. Create a UNION of two Lists (the second one having only one item) through LINQ and then let my BindingSource monitor the aggregate list.
3. Manually add items to the ComboBox and then monitor the List for changes.

Now I don't want to go for the 3rd option and lose binding advantages. The 1st option doesn't work because the newly created list is not linked to the original one and thus doesn't get updated. Combining two lists through LINQ would also create an independent List I guess.

So what I'm looking for here is what I'd call an `AggregateBindingSource` that would take one or more `List<T>`s as its DataSource and update my ComboBox automatically.

Or does someone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new List inside an own class(ViewModel) which consists of your List + the single item.
And databind this new List to your ComboBox.

1. If you are working with references, updating your List inside the ViewModel will automatically update the entries in your other List + Item.
2. If you are not working with references you have to update your List + Item. You could use an update function inside your ViewModel. But even if you are only using an integer for example I would put it inside an object so you can make use of the reference and then again you can use step 1.

So if you use one of the first two steps that you described in your post and be aware of the references there is no problem with creating a new List.

Comment: Creating a new list from an existing list (using constructor for example) doesn't in any way link the new list to the old one. It only creates a shallow copy (even if using references) of the original list. Any changes in the original list will not affect the contents of the new list.

Comment: ofc they are not really linked, but if you store the same references in both lists then they access the same elements.
So if you remove or insert in one list, you have to update. But if you just change some members of the elements, they will be updated in both lists.

Comment: Correct, but then you're simply suggesting case no. 3 i posted above, which I want to avoid, becuz the list is going to undergo a lot of insert/remove operations, so binding would really come handy.

Comment: I am not really aware of a solution to bind two sources to one combobox. Can you give some part of code that clarifies your problem because I don't really understand why you cant combine your list + item into the viewmodel list. and after modifying the list save it back to your first list + item.

maybe some snippets will help clear the issues